# How to download large zip file (1 -2 GB) using SpringBoot Rest API Apache CXF implementation?

Tags: spring-boot

How to download large zip file (1 -2 GB) using SpringBoot Rest API Apache CXF implementation ?

i have tried using Output Stream but no luck.

```
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file));

        return new StreamingResponseBody() {

            @Override
            public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream)
                    throws IOException {
                int nRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Writing some bytes..");
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it is able to download 500MB file, but it should work for 1-2 GB file as well :

```
try {
            String link = "https://s.basketbuild.com/uploads/devs/dianlujitao/oneplus3/cm13/cm-13.0-20160621-UNOFFICIAL-oneplus3.zip";
            URL url = new URL(link);

            System.out.println("Started reading the zip");

            File dir = new File("C:\\Softwares\\testdownload");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            String fileBaseName = "TestDownload";
            String fileExtension = "zip";
            System.out.println("Name: " + fileBaseName + '.' + fileExtension);
            File outputFile = new File(dir, fileBaseName + '.' + fileExtension);

            if (!outputFile.exists()) {

                outputFile.createNewFile();
            }

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            int n = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((n = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - duration;
            System.out.println("Finish in " + duration + "ms");

            inputStream.close();

            // release outputstream
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Your download has been finished");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something unexpected has happened!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something unexpected has happened!");
        }
```

Comment: In your example you have used URL , but i'm trying to read from the server directory or a filesystem. How can i modify for my need ?